# summing up values in a column by type in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table

[image: Table1]

I want to sum up the values for each type and create two other measures/columns (percentage and cumulative percentage) as shown in the table below
[image: Table2]

I tried with the following DAX

```
column = summarize(Table1, Table1[Type], "Total Value", sum(Table1[value]))
```

but I get the following error. I also tried with the `GroupBy` function, I get the same error.
`The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.`

Please help!

Comment: Does it have to be done in DAX or can you do it in the DB layer considering it is a database source?

Comment: The summarize function return a table. Error you are getting as you are trying to add the output of in a column. If you wants to play with results return from summarize, just use a Custom table to hole the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original data and Final output
[image]

Details of target data:
**For Value column Select aggregation as sum**

[image]

**For %GT Value column (percentage column in you case). Pull the value column once again in table visual and select "Show value as" then select "Percent of grand total"**
[image]

**For Cumulative percentage, create a quick measure for running total  and display it again as "Percent of grand total"**

[image]